# Magento 2.1 Cron Job MYSQL

Tags: magento-2.0, cron, mysql-indexes

I am having an issue with a cron job in Magento 2.1.  I have a job that I need to query a database to get some stock values for my Magento products, but the cron job gives me the following error:

```
HP Fatal error:  Class 'Meese\MWS\Cron\mysqli' not found in /chroot/home/ikonopsc/ikonops.com/html/app/code/Meese/MWS/Cron/Stock.php on line 28
```

Why is the mysqli object not available here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  It had to do with my namespace declaration.